# PC won't boot, keeps restarting

Tags: windows-10, boot

So I did something really stupid. I got a virus and I ran through a checklist I found on reddit to help get rid of it. Except, one of the steps told me to delete a registry key inside of something called Wow6432.node, but I accidentally deleted the whole thing.
 I tried resetting my PC, but it told me **"there was a problem resetting your computer"**
 Now, whenever I turn my computer on it just keeps restarting over and over. F8 and F12 no longer works so I can't boot from a USB.
Sorry for any typos, had to write this on my phone

Comment: Alright, so DEL worked. I guess now I should do the USB system image thingie and hopefully it will fix my hard drive

Comment: You can answer your own questions and accept it as the answer that worked, this gives the site a working answer for this question should anybody have the same problem, you can also add more detail to the question giving a broader base for searches of similar questions, thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using "DELETE" button to get into BIOS ? 
When you go into the BIOS you can change boot settings. 
I think f12 is fast boot setup and f8 will be safe mode.